Select and connect network printer
How do I select printer from printserver and connect it? What is the right way to do that?
This code works but how to write better code without creating temporary variable $x ?
$x = Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select printer to connect" | Select @{n="ConnectionName";e={"\\$($_.ComputerName)\$($_.Name)"}} | Select -ExpandProperty ConnectionName
Add-printer -ConnectionName $x

PS: Now I did it like this. If somebody can do better feel free to propose an answer.
 Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server |
 Sort-Object |
 Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select printer to connect" |
 Select  @{n="ConnectionName";e={"\\$($_.ComputerName)\$($_.Name)"}} |
 ForEach-Object {Add-Printer -ConnectionName $_.ConnectionName}


You can use a pipeline that directly connects to the Add-Printer command.

The following code:

Gets all printers on the print server.

This example uses a full domain path, but that is optional.


Uses regex to remove all printers names that do NOT start with "pl".

This useful in my situation, but remove this line if not desired.
Use any other regex as desired.


Sorts all the printers.
Uses Out-GridView to allow user to select the desired printer(s).
For each selected printer, format the connection name as '\\PrintServer\Printer'.

Get-Printer -ComputerName 'print-server.domain.com' |
Where-Object {$_.Name -match '(?i)PL.*'} |
Sort-Object |
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select printer to connect' |
Foreach-Object { Add-Printer -ConnectionName ('\\{0}\{1}' -f $_.ComputerName, $_.Name) }


You can avoid the temporary variable using a pipeline that connects to the Add-Printer command.
Add-Printer -ConnectionName (Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select printer to connect" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique |
    ForEach-Object { "\\$($_.ComputerName)\$($_.Name)" })

You pipe the output of Get-Printer into Out-GridView, the selection into ForEach-Object to format the connection name, and finally into Add-Printer.

It's good but "print-server" repited second time...

You're right, thanks. Can't test right now, feel free to edit.

Now code doesn't work. It seems one can't "$.ComputerName" and "$.Name" after "-ExpandProperty"
